# How to make app icon corners rounded in react native?

Tags: react-native, icons, appicon

I am trying to add rounded corners for the app install icon in react native, but it is not working. What i tried is adding the rounded corners of the white background of the logo icon in illustrator and then added the icon to the assets folder but it did not work. I watched a video by expo on youtube showing how to add app icons for ios and android, what i need is the android, so i removed the white background from illustrator and added only the logo, but a white background was added after i built the app. The corners that are for the app icon are always sharp corners after i add the rounded corners in illustrator. So i need your help to know what is the issue. Here is my app.json file:

```
    {
    "expo": {
        "name": "F1ian",
        "slug": "F1ian",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./App/assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./App/assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "com.f1ian.f1ian",
            "versionCode": 1,
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./App/assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./App/assets/favicon.png"
        },
        "extra": {
            "eas": {
                "projectId": "f5f4f061-dc1b-46a3-9474-4ce7f3c8dc36"
            }
        }
    }
}
```